# How can I handle copyrighted music?

Tags: game-industry, music, copyright

I have a curious question regarding on musics used in music rhythm game. In Guitar Hero for example, they used all different music albums in one program. Then, each album requires to ask permission to the owner, composer of the music, or the copyright owner of the music. Let's say, if you used 15 albums for the music rhythm game, then you have to contact 15 copyright owners and it might be that, for the game developer, that the profit earned goes to the copyright owner or owner of this music. For the independent game developers, was it okay if either used the copyright music by just mentioning the name of the singer included in the credits and in the music select screen or use the non-popular/old music that about 50 years ago? And, does still earn money for the indie game developers by making free downloadable game?

Comment: You can avoid asking for licenses for music, if you can make your game automatically process some file/youtube url etc. given by player. Now it's player's responsibility what music he will load into the game.

Comment: Just like in the Music Hero for the Android, for example. You may play downloaded mp3 songs if it is available within the folder on the external drive or SD Card. Is this what you mean, Markus von Broady?

Comment: Yes, you may also move responsibility away from you by making a social network of some sort, where everyone has a possibility of creating game logic, that is inserting his music and manually synchronize timestamps on these color buttons on '5-line-road' in Guitar Hero. Now you can even do the work yourself, but pretend it was some anonymous user when you get copyright problems ;)

Comment: Tell me if I was wrong, Markus. If the copyright owner died at by age, then this music can be considered  as use in public domain? How about the music that is mostly ignored or very old even if the owner was still alive, shall be used it directly without a permission for the music rhythm game?

Comment: I wouldn't go the public domain path. I didn't see a song being in public domain for a looong time, because even classical, hundreds years old music is orchestrated recently, and so, while composition is old, performance itself is new. I'm far from being an expert in the field, but if you want a public domain music, you probably should start looking for a digital gramophone.

Comment: As people have mentioned you can only use a non commercial license. The ones I am aware of that are OK are: Public Domain, Creative Commons Attribution (which you have to give credit), & Creative Commons. But like the answer below there is a Wiki link to get the facts.

Comment: Don't go guessing about things like this. Get proper legal advice from a real lawyer. "The internet told me so" is not a valid defense.

Comment: `even classical, hundreds years old music is orchestrated recently` - It's the performance (and any recordings of that performance) that is under copyright, not the actual composition itself.  You are free to reproduce anything from Mauler, Beethoven, etc., without paying any licensing fees.  You just can't go copying some other musician's performance of these classics...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain_in_the_United_States

Comment: @LarsViklund "My lawyer told me so" is not a valid defense either. "IANAL, go to lawyer" answers are obvious and don't input anything valuable to the discussion.

Comment: @Cypher, you are wrong, a composition is under copyright, Beethoven's composition went into public domain not because it was composition, but because it was old enough.

Comment: In the first Guitar Hero game they licensed all their music from a company that likely had ties with recording companies to reproduce all the music. They only used one original song and that's because Primus does not allow people to do covers of their music. Not until after people realized how popular they were did they people authorize real recordings. And in all reality if you have to ask these kinds of questions you can't afford to license real music for your game. The fees alone are expensive and that does not include the legal team you will need to help understand the terms of service.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady We're mincing words here, I think. The point is, the part that is in public domain is not the recording or the performance by other musicians or orchestras, but the notes that were written. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @Cypher

I guess, some rich and well developed companies can afford a couple of copyright musics to pay their licenses in order to use those musics in the music rhythm game for example. Public domain might be no restrictions in copyright and therefore it can be use without license payment but depends on the limitations due to compositions and the author. Otherwise, I'm gonna make my own music that is not too similar to the originals but making my own original composition for the game based something on the inspiration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither being an indie developer, nor releasing game for free, doesn't grant you some additional rights implicitly. You can either need to have agreement with rights owner, or use music that is in [public domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain) or other license (like [CC license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license)) that allows some sort of free usage.

Also as [Markus](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38747/how-can-i-handle-copyrighted-music/38749#comment65260_38747) correctly mentioned in comment, [Public Domain is a tricky thing](http://www.shockwave-sound.com/Articles/010_Copyrights_in_Public_Domain_music.html). So I guess you are more limited in classics than it may seems.

Comment: In the public domain, this is where you can find and use any music without copyright restriction. Plus, does it also include songs other than the US enlisted in the public domain, like Japanese songs or J-Pop for short for example?

Comment: I guess it's all matter of a international law reach. You probably can't be sued by Japanese court being in US, however they can sue you in US court. If you need really deep knowledge on a subject, then only profesional lawyer can help you.

Comment: Got it and thanks for the tip, Petr. True professionals must never give up in times of trials. ;-)

Comment: @DavidDimalanta `In the public domain, this is where you can find and use any music without copyright restriction.`  Be careful there.  Your statement, as worded, is incorrect.  You can *create* musical compositions that are in the public domain, but you cannot use another musician's recording.

Answer (score 8):

Distributing copyrighted music without a license from the copyright owner is a violation of copyright, and is illegal in most parts of the world.

Yes, it's still a violation of copyright even if you distribute it for free.

Yes, it's still a violation of copyright even if you credit the artist.

Yes, it's still a violation of copyright even if you hold your breath until you go blue.

Distributing copyrighted music without a license from the copyright owner is a violation of copyright.

**period**.

Comment: How come Guitar Hero used all of the copyright music? Does it take months to have a grant to use all these musics? And also, does the game developer have a split share for profit with the copyright owner of the music or the profit will belong always to the copyright owner of the music?

Comment: And one thing, Trevor, this copyright music will only be used as long as I joined their copyright owner's company for profit, right?

Comment: The reason they use real, well-known music is because real, well-known music makes the product appeal to more people, selling more, making it well worth going through the pains of licensing and acquiring performances of well-known songs.